# Agregar elemento al principio lista

Tags: c, lista, ordenamiento, dev-c++

Necesito agregar el contenido, al primer lugar de la lista. Pero no logro hacerlo, alguna ayuda? Este es el codigo que tengo.

```
if (primero == NULL) { //Por si el primer elemento es NULL
    printf("\nNuevo elemento:\n");
    printf("Nombre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nuevo->nombre);
    printf("Teléfono: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", nuevo->telefono);
    nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
    if (primero==NULL) {
        printf( "Primer elemento\n");
        primero = nuevo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
    else {
        ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
        }
else{ //En caso de que el primer lugar este ocupado
    primero -> siguiente = nuevo;
    printf("\nNuevo elemento:\n");
    printf("Nombre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nuevo->nombre);
    printf("Teléfono: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", nuevo->telefono);

    if (primero!=NULL) {
        primero=nuevo;
        ultimo=nuevo;
    }
    else {
        printf( "Primer elemento\n");
        /* el que hasta ahora era el ultimo tiene que apuntar al nuevo */
        ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;
        /* hacemos que el nuevo sea ahora el ultimo */
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
```

Comment: "Necesito agregar el contenido, al primer lugar de la lista." - Te refieres a que no se está escribiendo contenido en la variable `primero`? Puedes corroborar que estás inicializando la variable en NULL?

Comment: bienvenido a SO. Por favor echa un vistazo a [tour] y [ask] para entender cómo funciona este sitio. Así además ganarás tu primera medalla. Tu pregunta tiene problemas de forma que impiden darte una respuesta concreta. Faltan tipos de datos. Lo recomendable sería que publicases un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la final lo resolvi por mi propia cuenta, y vine a compartir el codigo. En caso de que alguien tenga el mismo problema, o necesite codigo de ejemplo.
Saludos.

## **funcion.c**

```
#include "cabecera.h"

void mostrar_menu() {
printf("\n\nMenu:\n=====\n\n");
printf("1.- Anadir contacto al inicio\n");
printf("2.- Anadir contacto al final\n");
printf("3.- Eliminar contactos\n");
printf("4.- Ordenar contactos por nombre\n");
printf("5.- Mostrar lista de contactos\n");
printf("6.- Salir\n\n");
printf("Elegir una opcion: ");
fflush(stdout);
}

void anadir_elemento(int num_nodo) {
struct _agenda *nuevo = NULL;
nuevo = (struct _agenda *) malloc (sizeof(struct _agenda));
if (nuevo==NULL) {
    printf( "No hay memoria disponible!\n");
    return;
 }

printf("\nNuevo elemento:\n");
printf("Nombre: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",nuevo->nombre);
printf("Teléfono: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", nuevo->telefono);
nuevo->num = num_nodo;

nuevo->siguiente = NULL;

if (primero==NULL) {
    printf( "Primer elemento\n");
    primero = nuevo;
    ultimo = nuevo;
    Ainicio = 0;
    Afinal = 0;
 }else {
    if (Ainicio == 1){
        nuevo->siguiente = primero;
        primero = nuevo;
        printf("Se agrego elemento al inicio de la lista");
        Ainicio = 0;
    }else{
        ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }

    if (Afinal == 1){
        printf("Se agrego elemento al final de la lista");
        Afinal = 0;
    }
}
}
```

## **main.c**

```
#include "cabecera.h"

int main() {
int opcion;
primero = (struct _agenda *) NULL;
ultimo = (struct _agenda *) NULL;
Ainicio = 0;
Afinal = 0;
int cant_nodos = 0;
do {
    mostrar_menu();
    scanf("%d", &opcion);
    fflush(stdin);
    switch ( opcion ) {
        case 1: cant_nodos++; Ainicio = 1; anadir_elemento(cant_nodos); break;
        case 2: cant_nodos++; Afinal = 1; anadir_elemento(cant_nodos); break;
        case 3: borrar_elemento(); break;
        case 4: ordenar_lista(); break;
        case 5: mostrar_lista(); break;
        case 6: liberarYSalir(); exit(1);
        default: printf( "Opción no válida\n" ); break;
    }
} while (opcion!='6');
return 0;
}
```

## **cabezera.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct _agenda {
char nombre[20];
char telefono[12];
int num;
struct _agenda *siguiente;
};

struct _agenda *primero, *ultimo;
int Afinal;
int Ainicio;

void mostrar_menu();
void anadir_elemento(int num_nodo);
void mostrar_lista();
void borrar_elemento();
void liberarYSalir();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como primero se barajan las cartas y luego se reparten, primero acomoda los datos en el arreglo según tu necesidad, *sin imprimirlos aún*. Luego, estando ordenados, imprímelos sin ningún otro tipo de condición. Saludos!

Comment: La teoría parece que te la sabes... ¿No has pensado nada acerca de decorar la respuesta con un ejemplo de la solución?